# WPF and EF with await async, freezing my UI

Tags: wpf, async-await, entity-framework-core

I think I am using the await async pattern incorrectly and am not sure how to fix it. I based my code on some pluralsights tutorials.

Basically I connect to the DB using EF and try to display the data by binding my ObservableCollection to the view.

I start with my getting my data drom teh datacontext something like this:

```
public interface ICountryData
{
    Task<List<Country>> GetAllAsync();
}

public class SqlCountryData : ICountryData
{
    private NodeDBContext _context;

    public SqlCountryData(NodeDBContext context)
    {
        _context = context; 
    }

    public async Task<List<Country>> GetAllAsync()
    {
        return await _context.Countries.Include(i => i.AvailableDocuments).OrderBy(c => c.CountryName).ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

Then call the GetAllAsync method:

```
public async Task LoadAsync()
    {
        List<Country> countries = await _countryData.GetAllAsync();

        Countries.Clear();
        foreach (Country s in countries)
        {
            Countries.Add(s);
        }


    }
```

I also stick all the items into my ObservebleCollection here with a foreach loop.

```
public ObservableCollection<Country> Countries { get; set; }
```

Which is in turn bound in my Viewmodel

```
<telerik:RadGridView x:Name="Countries"
                             GroupRenderMode="Flat"
                             RowIndicatorVisibility="Collapsed"
                             CanUserFreezeColumns="False"
                             ItemsSource="{Binding Countries}"
                             SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCountries}"
                             ShowSearchPanel="True" />
```

All this loads just fine. But it freezes the UI until it is done.

--- Edit to add some code showing how the LoadAsync is called ---

```
MainWindowViewModel _viewModel;

    public MainWindow(MainWindowViewModel viewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _viewModel = viewModel;
        DataContext = _viewModel;
        Loaded += MainWindow_LoadedAsync;
    }

    private async void MainWindow_LoadedAsync(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        await _viewModel.LoadAsync();
    }
```

Inside the MainWindow View Model:

```
public async Task LoadAsync()
    {
        await LookupViewModel.LoadAsync();
    }
```

Comment: Where and how are you calling `LoadAsync()`?

Comment: The actual time-consuming part is adding items to the Countries collection and thus populating the RadGridView. All that runs synchronously on the UI thread, and you won't see the an updated UI until it's done.

Comment: @redcurry I have added the code to the question above. As you can see I call the LoadAsync inside another method in the MainWindowVewModel. which in turn is called when the Loaded event is fired.

Comment: @Clemens I am aware of this, however I do not know how to transfer the data into an observablecollection without it. Also, even when I comment out the loop, it actually still freezes the UI. Maybe for a shorter time, but it still happens.

Comment: Since you still see a delay even when you comment out the loop, could it be that your query is taking some time? Perhaps try wrapping all that in a `Task.Run`.

Comment: Yes, it is taking some time. I am looking for a solution where it can take however long it wants. I would have assumed that calling it async would allow me to interact with the UI, while the data is loaded.

Comment: I haven't tried your code, but the async part is in `ToListAsync()`. If anything before that is taking time (even though it's supposed to be lazy), then you'll see a freeze in the UI.

Comment: @redcurry there is nothing else, even when removing all other code, the UI still freezes.

Comment: Even this part `_context.Countries.Include(i => i.AvailableDocuments).OrderBy(c => c.CountryName)`?